# Dropdown not working first time after login when redirecting to home page

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new on Angular 4 and with my current code, I am able to redirect to the homepage after login. However, the dropdown of my homepage is not working correctly. Note that when I refresh home page again then it is working fine.

example code : it is simple bootstrap dropdown toggle.

```
<li>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <i class="menu-icon fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
      <span class="menu-text"> Entity </span>

      <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
    </a>

    <b class="arrow"></b>

    <ul class="submenu nav-hide" style="display: none;">
      <li class="">
        <a [routerLink]="['broker','activeBrokerList']">
          <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
          Broker
        </a>

        <b class="arrow"></b>
      </li>

      <li class="">
        <a [routerLink]="['supplier','activeSupplierList']">
          <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
          Supplier
        </a>

        <b class="arrow"></b>
      </li>

      <li class="">
        <a [routerLink]="['customer','activeCustomerList']">
          <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
          Customer
        </a>

        <b class="arrow"></b>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

---

Thanks.

---

Answer (score 0):

Did you try another way for redirection? Directly pass the route like this

```
<a [routerLink]="/broker/{{activeBrokerList}}">
      <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
      Broker
    </a>
```

Here I am assuming that **activeBrokerList** is an instance variable from your component

Comment: Yes it is instance variable which i am initialising it in ngOnInit method through service. but in routerLink it is just url pattern. i am not using it as path param..

Comment: @BhavinHirpara Did you fix that?

Comment: @Ali-Alrabi Yes. But dont know what was the exact  issue.
May be it was because of the dependencies. I was using ace css and bootstrap both.